# Display count of filtered records

Tags: filter, count, display, amazon-quicksight

I am working on a dashboard with multiple filters.
I want to know if there is a way to display a count of filtered record.
E.g. If I hover on that particular filter after submitting the value, it should display the result.
Or if I could add a textbox somewhere around the main dashboard.

Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

I already checked countover and other functions and tried implementing in the code and at the analysis level but it never worked for me.

Cheers,
Anant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with the help of Insight.
I was able to add another visuals which were showing count of filtered records.